# No bounce of physics bodies?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have very simple code:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1.0);
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = nodeCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nodeCategory;
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        SKSpriteNode *node1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        SKSpriteNode *node2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
        node2.position = CGPointMake(0, -node1.frame.size.height/2+node2.frame.size.height/2);
        node1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node1.frame.size];
        node1.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        node1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nodeCategory;
        node1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory;
        node1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory;
        node1.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
        node1.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
        node1.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
        node1.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;

        [node1 addChild:node2];
        [self addChild:node1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Yet the node1 just falls through(affected by gravity) the screen without bouncing off the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give node1 a position:

```
node1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: That worked, but is it because the physics body of the scene that I defined was incorrect?

Comment: The physics body was fine. I don't fully know the root cause - it looks like a node needs its position set to enable physics but I'd need to test some more to be sure.